# TracError: Unsupported database type "mysql"

Tags: python, trac

My environment:

```
Debian: 9.3
trac/stable,now 1.2+dfsg-1 all [installed]
python-mysqldb/stable,now 1.3.7-1.1 amd64 [installed]
```

I follow the [`trac`](https://trac.edgewall.org/) manual, execute `trac-admin /usr/share/trac initenv` and get this trace:

```
Creating and Initializing Project
Initenv for '/usr/share/trac' failed. 
Failed to create environment.
Unsupported database type "mysql"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/admin/console.py", line 497, in do_initenv
    options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/core.py", line 128, in __call__
    self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/env.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.create(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/env.py", line 591, in create
    DatabaseManager(self).init_db()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/db/api.py", line 337, in init_db
    connector, args = self.get_connector()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/db/api.py", line 606, in get_connector
    scheme=scheme))
TracError: Unsupported database type "mysql"
```

I figured that the error is due to [`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/db/mysql_backend.py`](https://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/epydoc/trac.db-module.html) not being imported (and `MySQLConnector.get_supported_schemes()` doesn't even get executed). Problem is that I can not find any reference in the code for it to load this file. I can only find the interface `IDatabaseConnector`.

The postgres backend `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/db/postgres_backend.py` doesn't load either, but once I install `python-psycopg2` it magically starts to load. How so?

Can someone explain the python magic at work here and how I can get the `mysql` backend to work?

Comment: Naive question: what was the command to enable trace in initenv?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround is to edit /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-1.2.egg-info/entry_points.txt after install and remove the [mysql] suffix from: 
trac.db.mysql = trac.db.mysql_backend[mysql]

Comment: It would be cool if there were some explanation for why this worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me under Trac 1.4.3 after upgrading from 1.2 and editing `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-1.4.3.dist-info/entry_points.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and found after debugging that the package python-pymysql was somehow autoremoved (the upgrade actually had some broken dependency problems that had to be solved manually). After

```
$ apt install python-pymysql
```

trac was working again.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing this same issue, the following worked.

`$ pip install MySQL-python`

Of course, this is using a virutalenv.

```
cd /home/user/dev
mkdir TracEnv
mkdir TracEnv/TracProject
cd ./TracEnv/
virtualenv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install trac
pip install MySQL-python
trac-admin /home/user/dev/TracEnv/TracProject initenv
```